# Python plotly loading local image

Tags: python, plotly

Need an answer on the way in plotly to load an image from local file.

Searching the web with no real answer as to how plotly supports loading an image i.e. png file from local directory. Any help and guidance are appreciated

Comment: What do you want to do with the image? Have you seen https://plotly.com/python/images/ ?

Comment: I did look at the documentation, and the web before submitting this question. I could not find any answer.

Comment: The reason is to add a nice png file and add annotations on top

Comment: Add a png to what, where? You want to just display it as if it were a plot/chart?

Comment: Yes,1.  Add blueprint that I'd like to add it as background. 2. a nice benzene shape that will serve as a background for measure(s) display